# How to open wordpress post in new tab

Tags: wordpress

I'm using Hoot Business Theme, i can't find where I can insert target_blank" there is no loop.php in this theme. Is there any other way to open wordpress post in new tab?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve this without messing about in your template files is with jQuery:

```
$('a.addSomethingBlogSpecificHere').attr('target','_blank');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add target="_blank" in anchor tag HTML like :

```
<a href="#"  target="_blank" > Label Name </a>
```